# Solution verification: Calculating a value using iterated sum/product notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> Calculate 
>   $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{5}\left(3k-10\right)\right)\prod_{r=1}^{4}r$$

So what I did first is expand each notation as it is, so

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{5}\left(3k-10\right)\right)\prod_{r=1}^{4}r = (-10-7-4-1+2+5) \cdot (1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4)= -15\cdot 24 = -360$$

Can anyone help me verify this is correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct and your steps make sense.

As further evidence, [Wolfram Alpha also gets the same answer](https://goo.gl/5Wj6uV)

---

*Making this a community wiki answer since I don't really have anything else to add beyond a "yes, you're right."*